# Sitecore Item Display Name is encoded automatically

Tags: sitecore

When editing a Sitecore item that contains HTML in the Display Name (e.g. *Title*), the HTML is encoded immediately. Editing Display Name a second time shows that `<em>Title</em>` has been converted to `&lt;em&gt;Title&lt;/em&gt;`.

We don't have any custom code that would do this; is there a configuration parameter or something that would control how display name is encoded?

[EDIT]
To clarify, if I edit an item's Display Name to add HTML, and then edit it a second time, the HTML contained in the Display Name has been encoded. There are several older items that contain HTML in the Display Name field and it is rendered correctly.

For example, first I edit an item's Display Name to add emphasis tags...

[image: Adding HTML]

...you can see how the Display Name is updated in the content tree.

[image: HTML updated]

However, if I edit the item again, Sitecore encodes the HTML as show below...

[image: HTML encoded]

Oddly, there are other (older) items in the content tree that already have HTML in their Display Name, and the HTML is correctly rendered (see below item with  tag in the display name).

[image: Item with HTML in display name]

My question is: what could cause the HTML to be encoded?

To answer the question "Why would you want to do this in the first place?", I would respond with the answer that this is legacy code that used to be working and is now suddenly not. I'm not building a new system; this is an existing web site that I'm troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think this would make sense. The DisplayName is i.e. also shown in the Content Editor, where Bold and Italic wouldn't be great. Why would you like to do this? I would suggest you to create a new fields where you can insert what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added screenshots and clarification to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a little bit confusing.  What exactly are you expecting to see vs. what you are actually seeing?  Display Name is a simple text field, it's not rich text... I don't believe Sitecore is doing any encoding here.

Now you can make Sitecore skip the decoding step for single-line text fields by removing the Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue from the renderField pipeline.  Then you'll get exactly whatever is in that field rather than `&lt;em&gt;Title&lt;/em&gt`;

OK, I think I get why your question is confusing me now.  The input from you question was decoded?

EDIT: BTW, this pipeline entry GetTextFieldValue was a recent addition... some time between 6.3 and 6.6.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've added more information + some screenshots to my question to help clarify.

Comment: If absolutely necessary, you can edit the raw value in the database to get the output you really want.  What's probably happening is that Sitecore is encoding your input in the convertToRuntimeHtml pipeline.  Old items look OK because you haven't tried to edit them... if you do, they'll probably get encoded the same way.  BTW, your question is still a little confusing... look at the text inside the parentheses of your edit.  Use a code block to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I formatted the code in my question as a code block to make it more clear what is happening. I typed this out quickly and didn't proofread like I should have :-).

Comment: Old items look OK even when editing. They are not encoded when editing. Sorry, I should have made it more clear that I've tried this as well. If I edit an older item it appears as originally entered in the Display Name edit dialog. This is a little baffling.

Comment: Well, that tells you that the encoding is happening when you save the value then, right?  So now find the pipeline where that is happening... adjust as necessary.

Comment: Nope, I was wrong... at least in Siteore 6.6, the encoding is happening when the value is read from the DB.  Are you sure you're looking at the same field ID for these two items?  I have trouble seeing how they behave differently unless they are two different data types.